# Microsoft dynamic CRM Custom Workflow

Tags: workflow, crm

CAN we add the list of entity reference ,,as an output parameter of custom workflow
because i want to add multiple cc recipient in sending email by workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible and you will have to find other way of completing your task because supported input/output parameters for custom workflow activities are :

- Bool
- DateTime
- Decimal
- Double
- EntityReference
- Int
- Money
- OptionSetValue
- String

You can find detailed description here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984.aspx#AttributesandMicrosoftDynamicsCRMTypes

Please provide your full scenario and I will try to help you.